# JQuery append is closing form tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I can't figure this out for the life of me. Jquery keeps closing the form that I create (instead of `<tr><form> ... <td></td> ... </form></tr>` it creates `<tr><form></form>...` I've looked at lots of questions regarding this and each suggestion is to use an intermediate string, which I am. Hopefully someone can pick up on something I'm missing :)

```
var my_table = $("#output_table").find("tbody");    
// Loop over JSON data and create table rows
$.each(json.data, function(index, field) {
    var html_string = "<tr><form action='addtoDB.php' method='POST'>" +
        "<input type='hidden' name='instructor' value=" + field.instructor + ">" +
        "<input type='hidden' name='section' value=" + field.section + ">" +
        "<input type='hidden' name='course_id' value=" + field.course_id + ">" +
        "<input type='hidden' name='course_name' value=" + field.course_name + ">" +
        "<td class='row_head'>" + field.instructor + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + field.section + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + field.start_time + " - " + field.end_time + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + field.weekdays + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + field.total + "/" + field.capacity + "</td>";
    if (field.open) {
        html_string += "<td><input type='submit' value='open to enroll' class='disabled' disabled></td>";
    } else {
        html_string += "<td><input type='submit' value='Notify me' class='enabled'></td>";
    }
    html_string += "</form></tr>";
    my_table.find('tr:last').after(html_string);
});
```

I've tried removing `<form>` and `<tr>` from the string entirely and adding it at the end with:
`my_table.append("<tr><form>" + html_string + "</form></tr>");` but I get the same effect. So confused!

Comment: `<form>` is invalid child of `<tr>`...therein lies your problem. Has nothing to do with jQuery directly, it's the browser not liking your invalid code

Comment: You're trying to abuse <tr> tags and the browser is not letting you.

Comment: WOW. Alright, any suggested fixes? Simply switching the order doesn't seem to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actualy not a `jquery` problem but a browser one. Browsers won't let you do that because the only elements allowed to be children of `tr` are `th` and `td`.

Source : [w3c documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element)

Comment: Thanks. Got any suggestions to do something similar to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Yes, for example, you could just get rid of the `<form></form>` elements and then `onclick` on your `<input type='submit'>` you call `addtoDB.php` by `AJAX`

Comment: So something like `$("#output_table").on("click","input[type=submit]", function(e)...`

How would I get those hidden input fields now? `$(this).parent().("input[name=...]")` ?

Comment: Just before getting into more details, is it an affordable solution to use CSS to show your `form` just as it was in your `<tr>` while in the markup it is actualy outside of it ?

Comment: Ok then problem solved? :) You just keep your `<form action='addtoDB.php' method='POST'>` and no need for using `ajax`

Comment: I still don't know how to get the hidden inputs :(

Comment: You get them from your `addtoDB.php` as `$_POST['instructor']`, `$_POST['section']`, etc

Comment: Nah, I need them in javascript since I parse them and create some input fields based on them. I guess JQuery confuses me. Like `$("body").on("submit","form.class", function(e)` works but `$("form").on("submit",".class", function(e)` doesn't... Ugh

Comment: Then just use `$("input[name='instructor']").val()` to get them :)

Comment: That will only get the first input field! How do I get the one relative to the submit button pressed? I tried `$(this).closest('tr').find("input[name='instructor']").val()`, which doesn't work :D Thanks for being so patient btw... I'm almost there haha

Comment: Oh ok, you mean that you have many forms with the same hidden inputs?

Comment: No, like you can see in my code there are four hidden inputs on each row. When I click "submit" I want JQuery to figure out which row was 'submitted' and get the hidden inputs for that particular row.

Comment: OK, can you provide a jsfiddle so I can see your code in action?

Comment: Code is too long to post to JSFiddle. Got it 'mostly' working now. I deleted the form entirely, and replaced the submit buttons with just `type=button` and an `on("click")` event. Then: `$(this).parent().parent().('input[name=instructor]').val()` will fetch the hidden field. But it only gets the first whitespace-delimited word (so if the field is "blue chicken" it will get "blue". If you have any idea why, I would be grateful. I'm going to bed now before I hurt myself from frustration.

Comment: Ok, this should work : `$(this).parents('tr').children("input[name='instructor']").val()`. See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngt2ddmr/1/).

Comment: The above gives you 'blue children' as requested

Comment: OMG THANK YOU. I didn't have single quotes when I was adding the hidden fields: `value=" + field.instructor + ">" +...` so I changed it to `value='" + field.instructor + "'>" +...` Thanks so much for being patient and helping me through this :) Have a great night